# startx fails to start

Tags: 13.10, xorg, startup

I ran the Software Manager and now startx doesn't start anymore. After I start my laptop and log in, the screen stays stuck on the login page (I tried with both gdm and lightdm).

Switching to console and starting `startx` manually I get the following errors:

```
mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/tmp/serverauth.XXXXXXXXXX’: Permission denied
xauth:  file  does not exist
xauth:  unable to link authority file , use -n
use: X [:<display>] [option]
-a #                   default pointer acceleration (factor)
-ac                    disable access control restrictions
-audit int             set audit trail level
-auth file             select authorization file
...
Initializing built-in extension DRI2
Loading extension GLX
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Error:            Cannot open "/tmp/filegRxhGH" to write keyboard description
>                   Exiting
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Error:            Cannot open "/tmp/fileb9Lgzg" to write keyboard description
>                   Exiting
XKB: Failed to compile keymap
Keyboard initialization failed. This could be a missing or incorrect setup of xkeyboard-config.
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Failed to activate core devices.(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: unexpected signal 2
```

I found reference to multiple similar problems and have tried various things.

Making sure I have enough space disk: here's a `df` output, it doesn't seem to be the problem.

```
root@blackbox:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6        22G   18G  2.9G  87% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           376M  1.2M  374M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M  4.0K  100M   1% /run/user
```

The permission of my .Xauthority file are wrong at startup:

```
root@blackbox:~# ls /home/florian/.Xauthority -al
-rw------- 1 root root 155 Mar 23 17:10 /home/florian/.Xauthority
```

However if I `chown` the file and reboot I still have the same problem.

I have uninstalled (with `purge`) and reinstalled `xserver-xorg` and ran `dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` but no luck.

**Update** If I stop the display manager before retrying to start `startx` I get the following errors:

```
xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /home/florian/.Xauthority
...
Loading extension GLX
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
>                   Ignoring extra symbols
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
>                   Ignoring extra symbols
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Compat map for group 2 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 3 redefined
>                   Using new definition
> Warning:          Compat map for group 4 redefined
>                   Using new definition
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
>                   Ignoring extra symbols
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
(II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
xinit: connection to X server lost
^M
waiting for X server to shut down (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

xinit: unexpected signal 2
xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /home/florian/.Xauthority
```

The only solution I found is to run `startx` as root, then it works but I shouldn't need to do that!

**Update 2** The best solution I found so far is to switch to virtual terminal, remove the .Xauthority file then run ´startx´. But I need to do this every time I boot.

Comment: Are you stopping the display manager (e.g. `sudo service lightdm stop`) before attempting to `startx` from the virtual terminal?

Comment: The log complains about not being able to write the keyboard configuration. Are the permissions on /tmp correct? (should be drwxrwxrwt).

Comment: @JoS yes, that's correct.

Comment: @steeldriver I wasn't, I tried now and got other errors; I updated the question.

Comment: And what if you stop lightdm _and_ remove the root-owned `.Xauthority` file?

Answer (score 4):

remove Xauthority THEN :

`alt + ctrl + F1` THEN :

`sudo pkill -9 Xorg` THEN:

`startx`

hope this helps

Comment: This works, but I need to do it every time I boot.

Comment: hello , what GUI you are using gnome or kde ?

Comment: @MasterScrat, add it to your ~/.profile or /etc/rc.local file.

Comment: For me, `alt + ctrl + F1` logs out.

Answer (score 3):

Try to remove your `.Xauthority` file:

```
sudo rm /home/florian/.Xauthority
```

And restart your system (with your normal user account)

Comment: Nope, this doesn't change anything :(

Comment: I added more of the failing `startx` output in the question

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this problem with:

```
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp /var/tmp
```

Answer (score -1):

You're getting that error because your user doesn't have permission to access your /tmp folder.  Change the permissions of your /tmp folder and it should work just fine.

```
chmod 755 /tmp -R
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer and is in fact dangerous to run. Recursively changing the permissions on a system folder is a bad idea in general, but this command will just break a user's install. Please refer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71625) for a proper solution.